# HTML object autoplay off

Tags: html, video, object-tag

I am using the object tag for displaying documents. PDFs, images and videos. While displaying videos, the autoplay tag is there by default. I have tried to disabled it without success:

Note: I am not using the video tag, but the object tag.

```
  <object autostart="false" class="document" type="text/html" data='<%= make_https(card.docu.url) %>'>
    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
  </object>
```

I already tried autostart="0", 0, false. I run out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated. Otherwise I will have to destroy the attribute with ES6, something that I want to avoid.

Edit: after trying autostart="false" and autoplay="false", still did not work. I am affecting the object tag, not the video tag, who has by default the autoplay:

[image]

How can I remove the autoplay in the video tag, if I am using the object tag?

Thanks

Comment: So despite the URL ending in `.mp4`, this actually returns an HTML document? Of course you can not remove the autoplay attribute from the video element _at all_ in this case - because the Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with 3rd-party content from a different domain this way. Trying to slap any autostart or autoplay attributes on the object element is nonsense as well, because HTML documents don’t “auto play” to begin with. The object element doesn’t even have such attributes (so at most they could be evaluated by a script or something.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? (@CBroe, no, this is just how developer tools show an <object> element that renders video; at least that's how they do in Firefox these days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post sits here for 3 years with no answer.

I've encountered a similar situation, what I did was to add `onload` function to pause the videos (works in FF 88 and chromium 90, on ubuntu):

```
<object class="document" type="text/html" data='<%= make_https(card.docu.url) %>'  onload="this.contentDocument.querySelector('video').pause()">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 1 and 0 value for true or false.

Comment: In the first line after the code, I mentioned that I tried "0", 0 and false

Comment: still autoplaying :(

Comment: Can you add to <param name="autoStart" value="false"/> too?

Comment: not working. i edit the answer to show the problem. problem is that we affect the object tag, not the video tag